# AIC and BIC formula in R

Tags: r, regression

I am going to compute AIC and BIC of a linear model without using build in function AIC() and BIC() in R. But every time I compute AIC and BIC from formula and corresponding R function, I get different results. any idea?

My R code is like this:

```
set.seed(123456)
   b = c ( 1:5 )  
   n=100
   nb=length(b)
   x = matrix ( rnorm ( nb*n) ,ncol = nb )
   y =  x %*% b + rnorm ( n) 

   l=lm(y~x+0)
   AIC(l)
   residual= (y-x %*% l$coef)
   2*nb-2*sum(dnorm(residual, 0, sd(residual), log=T))
```

**UPDATE: I have updated the question based on @nongkrong comment and it works well now.**

Comment: you havent computed the likelihood here, you need to use `dnorm` with the residuals, something along the lines of `2*5-2*sum(dnorm(residuals(l), 0, sd(residuals(l)), log=T))`, or plug in your `MSR` for residuals

Comment: thanks. can you explain your answer a bit more in an answer. Then I tick this question as closed.

Comment: well, the basic idea is that to calculate likelihood you need to assume a distribution of the residuals, then calculate the probability of seeing the data given this assumption.  Here, you use a normal distribution for regular linear regression.

Comment: you get difference values cause you are generating random numbers.. and not setting a seed..